# Fill a transparent image with background color

Tags: php, image, function

I have pictures like this http://drksde.tk/images/F3-big.png on my website, are used for the avatars of the users. And every user can change the color of the background, because the images have a transparent background.
I done it!! thanks a lot for your help!!

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){ 
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h); 
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct); 
}

$background = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

$color = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 150, 0);
imagefill($background, 0, 0, $color);

$avatar = imagecreatefrompng('F3-big.png');

imagecopymerge_alpha($background, $avatar, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($background);

imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($avatar);
```

?>

And the final avatar: http://drksde.tk/images/avatar2.png

Comment: why bother with this, when you could layer ANOTHER background behind this image that would simply "leak through" the transparent parts of the main background?

Comment: That is what I have been doing, but I want to let the users save thier custom avatar and use it on another sites or IM clients etc.

Comment: maybe I didnt understand this question, but why not to fill and then place avatar upon filled?

Comment: It does the same, the problem is that I don't know very well how to do it, I tried a los of things and that code is the only one that worked, but the final picture looks very ugly.

Comment: Ah, I understood. You need antialiasing =)

Comment: Nope, the problem is that the old script doesn't managed very well the alpha channel